# Trying to improve sound quality with ALSA

Tags: alsa

I'm trying to make ALSA 1.0.23 to use different resampling algorithm. I did some research on the Internet and found that putting the line `defaults.pcm.rate_converter "<library>"` into either `/etc/asound.conf` or `~/.asoundrc` will tell ALSA to use different resampling algorithm.

However, it doesn't seem to work. Putting the following line into ~/.asoundrc `defaults.pcm.rate_converter "speexrate_best"` doesn't have any effect on either CPU usage or the list of loaded libraries (doing `lsof -n | grep speex` while playing something yields nothing). Although, the following snippet forces ALSA to use new resampling algorithm:

```
pcm.!default {
    type rate
    slave {
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        rate 48000
    }
    converter "speexrate_best"
}
```

Doing so makes CPU usage to 10-15% and makes two new shared libraries appear in the list of `lsof`, but software mixing stops working and I can't play multiple audio files.

I'm probably missing something obvious. What can be an issue here?

Comment: Hi user310, did the trick improve your audio? Do you know a way to test if alsa is already using the best possible rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like mplayer was doing resampling all the way long. Playing some wav files with `aplay` shows that the new resampling algorithm is being used as intended.